# binding-key with range on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I need create binding key with range parameter, Have is Rabbitmq special characters for it? For example:
1. #.key.# - any names before and after key word

??.key.?? - for point to range like SQL (>10 <20).key.(>10 <20)

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to do what you want with a current exchange.  You may be able to do it with a custom exchange though. You could try this one https://github.com/tonyg/script-exchange or write your own. Check out the HowTo on this page http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html#going-further for writing your own custom exchange.